# How to divide data into different groups with one continously data recording

Tags: r, dataframe

There is one recording data, but it contains three replications, which means set A, B, and C were recorded in one continous data, for we only have one sensor that can record. The trouble I met right now is that I don't know what variable I can use to filter this data and distribute them into three sets through R, so that I can analyse different sets separately without manually organising data.

I have tried to use slope between each two points as the variable for filtering, but seems not so well and I am stuck. The code below is the step that I create variable slope in.
And the graph in the end is what data looks like in the plot.

```
##create the column of slope
d<-c()

for (i in 2:1017)
{
  d[i-1]<-coefficients(lm(da1$o2sat_exp[i-1:i]~da1$times[i-1:i]))[2]
}
d<-format(round(d,3), nsmall=3)
da1<-cbind(da1[1:1016,],d)

##filtering data

da1A<-filter(da1,d == -0.001)
```

Graph of three experiment sets with one sensor for recording:
[image: Graph of three experiment sets with one sensor for recording]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You could try to use some sort of clustering (e.g. kmeans) as it seems that the three sets have differences in mean. However, as two sets seem to be very similar it might not work. 
Also note, that it would be beneficial to share your data e.g. with using `dput` to create a reproducible example.